# how to set regionId and region Name in default shipping address

Tags: magento-1.8

how to get the value of regionId and region Name and also how could i set regionId and region name to setDefaultShipping address

Comment: Can you add more information about what you want to do and where?

Comment: $address = Mage::getModel("customer/address");
$address->setCustomerId($customer_id)
  ->setCountryId('IN')
        ->setPostcode($postal_code)
  ->setStreet($street)
        ->setCity($city)
  ->setRegionId('515')
        ->setRegion($state)
  
        ->setTelephone($telephone)
        ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
        ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');  this is my code but i am unable to set state column

Comment: i have state name like tamilnadu in $state variable on that i have to set regionId. how could i get

Comment: Ok have you already charged these regions in the database?

Comment: yes i created a db named xyz in that i have state details. i retrieve state info and stored in $state. so that, i get region id from that state

Comment: I mean, have you added those regions to `directory_country_region` table in magento db?

Comment: yes i added ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all regions correctly created in the magento table: `directory_country_region` you just need to set values to the customerAddress model and save it that way:

```
$address = Mage::getModel("customer/address");
$address->setData(array(
    'customer_id' => [existent customer_id]
    'country_id' => [country_id as figure in directory_country and directory_country_region] 
    'region_id' => [region_id as figure in directory_country_region]
    'region' => [default_name in directory_country_region or name in directory_country_region_name]
    ... other fields ...
))
->save();
```

country_id, and region_id will be validated against these tables so you have to ensure that these ids and the relation between country and region are ok.

Place this code inside a try..catch to see any error while save.

I think that should be enough, if doesn't work take a look at the **saveAction** method in:

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php

Is a different approach starting from the Customer Model instead the CustomerAddress Model.

Edited to fit comments contents:

To get the region_id based on region_name you have different options depending every case, so if you have to find just one region do:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/region_collection');
$collection->addFieldToFilter('country_id', array('eq' => {country_id}))
    ->addFieldToFilter('default_name', array('eq' => {region_name}));

$regionId = $collection->getFirstItem()->getRegionId();
```

If you need more than one region_id it's better to get an array to mapping:

```
$conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
/* @var $conn Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql */
$select = $conn->select()
  ->from('directory_country_region', array('default_name', 'region_id'))
  ->where('country_id = ?', '{country_id}');

$regionPairs = $conn->fetchPairs($select); 

// This will return an array like that:

array(
    'New York' => 512,
    'Atlanta' => 134,
    ...
)
```

So you can use it to map your region/state names.

however is best to use region code than names to avoid special chars problems, so if can add regions `code` and use a similar approach based on code instead `default_name`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i have still doubt, what i need is , i have region name. by this region name,i have to get region id... could u help me an this angle.please

Comment: @MonishaM15 i just edited the answer to fit your comments questions, plase take a moment for edit your question with the comments contents in order to make this post understandable and useful for all. Thanks!

Comment: Is this possible in do with observer

Comment: why not? i'm sure you can try it in any place you want... and then tell if it works

Comment: I dont know where i miss. yet i am not get the answer

Comment: what part you do not understand?

Comment: i do it with in observer i got error

Comment: ok... where you got the error?

Comment: i could not get the default address when create new customer

Comment: if i give ->setRegionId('53') it gives the correct state.but i dont give the static value to setRegion

Comment: boy i'm doing my best to help you but is sooooo complicated to understand what are you trying to do and where... can you please take a minute and try to explain: 1)Where are you making the changes, 2) with which data? 3) what is the result you are looking for 4) What is the actual result you get. thanks

Comment: @MonishaM15 soo any news about that?

Comment: Thank you Mauro. I tried and get answer in another way. i post my answer.

Comment: from ur idea i get the answer Thank you very much @ Mauro

Comment: Great! So please upvote the answer or mark it as resolved if it was useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

$connections= Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$select = $connections->select()
            ->from('customer_branch_address', array('*'))
            ->where('branch=?',$branch_name);

            $rowsArray = $connections->fetchAll($select);
            foreach($rowsArray as $rows) {
            $state=$rows['state'];
          }
$select1 = $connections->select()

            ->from('directory_country_region_name', array('*'))
            ->where('name=?',$state);
            $rowsArray = $connections->fetchRow($select1);
            foreach($rowsArray as $rows) {
            $Stateid=$rowsArray['region_id'];
            }
->setRegionId($Stateid)

Comment: I am tried this. is working... i hope it is helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

$regionId =$this->getRequest()->getPost('state_name');
$region = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->load($regionId);

Another way to get Region Id